# spinxsql combine match and filter

Tags: sphinx, manticore-search

I use Manticore Search. Fork of Spinx.
I'am trying to use Full text search. But problem in json fields. So I fond solutions via ANY()

```
ANY(client_user.login = "test" FOR client_user IN client_users)
```

It works great. But when I try to use it with common full text search - it's not work

PHP code like this

```
$client = new \Manticoresearch\Client($config);
$search = new \Manticoresearch\Search($client);
$search->setIndex('clients');
$search->expression('cond1', 'ANY(client_user.login = "'.$query.'" FOR client_user IN client_users)');
$bool = new \Manticoresearch\Query\BoolQuery();
$bool->should(new \Manticoresearch\Query\Equals('cond1', 1));
$bool->should(new \Manticoresearch\Query\QueryString($query.'*'));
$search->search($bool);
$results = $search->get();

print '<pre>'.print_r($search->getBody(), true).'</pre>';
```

Like query array:

```
Array
(
    [index] => clients
    [script_fields] => Array
        (
            [cond1] => Array
                (
                    [script] => Array
                        (
                            [inline] => ANY(client_user.login = "test" FOR client_user IN client_users)
                        )

                )

        )

    [query] => Array
        (
            [bool] => Array
                (
                    [should] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [equals] => Array
                                        (
                                            [cond1] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [query_string] => test*
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Response is empty.

If I use sql:

```
select login, name, ANY(client_user.login = 'test' FOR client_user IN client_users) as cond1 from clients where cond1 = 1 OR match('test*');
```

I have an error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected '(' near '('test*')'

Comment: You can't use OR in the WHERE clause.

Comment: In fact can't do a field OR attribute filter. Can only combine with AND. Probably easiest solution is to convert you attribute filter to field match. Or IS supported in the MATCH field query/filter

Comment: I need to filter via JSON field. Via login attribute. Solution I think is to duplicate logins in separate field and use it in Match

Comment: Yes can't use JSON with Fields. So yes just duplicate the data from JSON into a plain string for indexing as a field